# Render latex in titles

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

When I'm browsing the mathematics SE, all the titles have horrendous looking latex code that looks beautiful when compiled, except it's not compiled in titles (only in body).

Comment: Indeed, didn't see that when I posted... Thanks